# saving input data to global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with a simple file input.
I'm trying to get the width, height and dataURL of multiple images and save them to global variables, but all that's saved is "undefined".

When I tried to make a "demo-fiddle" the "onchange"-event doesn't even seem to fire.

can anyone help me out?

Here's the code of the demo-fiddle:

```
    var WIDTH = [];
    var HEIGHT = [];
    var SRC = [];

    $(window).load(function()
    {
    grabData();
    displayImgs();
});

function grabData()
    {   
        $("#fileInput").on("change",function(e)
        {
            var file = e.target.files; 

            for(var i = 0; i<file.length; i++)
            {
                var reader= new fileReader();
                var img = new Image();

                reader.onload = function(e)
                {
                    SRC = e.target.result;
                    img.onload = function() 
                    {
                        WIDTH = this.width;
                        HEIGHT = this.height;
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                console.log(WIDTH);
            }
            console.log(WIDTH);
        });
    }
function displayImgs()
{
    /*display images*/
    for(var i = 0; i<SRC.length; i++)
    {
        $("body").append("<img src="+SRC[i]+" width="+WIDTH[i]+" height="+HEIGHT[i]+">");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the link to the fiddle.

Comment: It's seems that img.onload is not called at all, did you try to use console.log within img.onload? Because img.src is not set.

Comment: Furthermore call displayImgs within a callback function like img.onload

Comment: Here's the link to the js-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ot3sz4o/

yes, I tried that, but even if I set a console.log directly behind the onchange-event nothing fires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code, tested in fiddle and working  -  http://jsfiddle.net/02468Lr9/

```
var WIDTH = [];
var HEIGHT = [];
var SRC = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    grabData();
    ;
});

function grabData() {   
    $("#fileInput").on("change",function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files; 

        for(var i = 0; i<file.length; i++) {
            var reader= new FileReader();
            var img = new Image();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                SRC.push(e.target.result);
                img.onload = function() {
                    alert(this.width);
                    WIDTH.push(this.width);
                    HEIGHT.push(this.height);

                    displayImgs();
                }

                img.src = e.target.result;
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);            
        }
    });
}
function displayImgs()
{
    /*display images*/
    for(var i = 0; i<SRC.length; i++)  {
        console.log(WIDTH);
        $("body").append("<img src="+SRC[i]+" width="+WIDTH[i]+" height="+HEIGHT[i]+">");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The log result is undefined because you log it outside the onload function, and for that it runs before the images load and the value is still undefined.